# OpenMP atomic and non-atomic reads/writes produce the same instructions on x86_64

Tags: c++, openmp, x86-64, atomic, memory-fences

According to the OpenMP Specification (v4.0), the following program contains a possible data race due to unsynchronized read/write of `i`:

```
int i{0}; // std::atomic<int> i{0};

void write() {
// #pragma omp atomic write // seq_cst
   i = 1;
}

int read() {
   int j;
// #pragma omp atomic read // seq_cst
   j = i; 
   return j;
}

int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel
   { /* code that calls both write() and read() */ }
}
```

Possible solutions that came to my mind are shown in the code as comments:

1. to protect write and read of `i` with `#pragma omp atomic write/read`,
2. to protect write and read of `i` with `#pragma omp atomic write/read seq_cst`,
3. to use `std::atomic<int>` instead of `int` as a type of `i`.

Here are the compilers-generated instructions on x86_64 (with `-O2` in all cases):

```
GNU g++ 4.9.2:               i = 1;        j = i;
original code:               MOV           MOV
#pragma omp atomic:          MOV           MOV
// #pragma omp atomic seq_cst:  MOV           MOV
#pragma omp atomic seq_cst:  MOV+MFENCE    MOV    (see UPDATE)
std::atomic<int>:            MOV+MFENCE    MOV

clang++ 3.5.0:               i = 1;        j = i;
original code:               MOV           MOV
#pragma omp atomic:          MOV           MOV
#pragma omp atomic seq_cst:  MOV           MOV
std::atomic<int>:            XCHG          MOV

Intel icpc 16.0.1:           i = 1;        j = i;
original code:               MOV           MOV
#pragma omp atomic:          *             *
#pragma omp atomic seq_cst:  *             *
std::atomic<int>:            XCHG          MOV

* Multiple instructions with calls to __kmpc_atomic_xxx functions.
```

What I wonder is why the GNU/clang compiler does not generate any special instructions for `#pragma omp atomic` writes. I would expect similar instructions as for `std::atomic`, i.e, either `MOV+MFENCE` or `XCHG`. Any explanation?

**UPDATE**

g++ 5.3.0 produces `MFENCE` for `#pragma omp atomic write seq_cst`. That is the correct behavior, I believe. Without `seq_cst`, it produces plain `MOV`, which is sufficient for non-SC atomicity.

There was a bug in my Makefile, g++ 4.9.2 produces `MFENCE` for CS atomic write as well. Sorry guys for that.

Clang 3.5.0 does not implement the OpenMP SC atomics, thanks Hristo Iliev for pointing this out.

Comment: My GCC 4.9.2 generates an `mfence` immediately after `movl $1, i(%rip)` for the sequentially consistent atomic write.

Comment: Also, Clang 3.5.0 only supports the regular non-sequentially consistent atomics. It doesn't even have a full OpenMP 3.1 support - see [here](http://wongmichael.com/2015/08/19/clang-3-7-will-have-full-openmp-3-1-support-followed-by-openmp-4/).

Comment: Your GCC 4.9.2 generates `mfence` for OpenMP SC atomic write? That is, with `i` being of type `int`? My GCC only for `std::atomic<int>`.

Comment: I just realized that g++ 5.3.0 produces `mfence` for SC OpenMP atomic writes. So, the problem was with (my) g++ 4.9.2.

Comment: I wonder how your 4.9.2 is different from my 4.9.2. I doubt that the machine specification in GCC could be different. What OS and distribution are you using?

Comment: @Hristo Iliev: You are absolutely right, I had a bug in my Makefile, a wrong source was used :(. Guys, I am so sorry about that. Thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

1. The compiler is not obligated to convert C++ code containing a data race into bad machine code.  Depending on the machine memory model, the instructions normally used may already be atomic and coherent.  Take that same C++ code to another architecture and you may start seeing the pragmas cause differences that didn't exist on x86_64.
2. In addition to potentially causing use of different instructions and/or extra memory fence instructions, the atomic pragmas (as well `std::atomic` and `volatile`) also constrain the compiler's own code reordering optimizations.  They may not apply to your simply case, but you certainly could see that common-subexpression elimination, including hoisting computations outside a loop, may be affected.

Comment: I agree, however, `MOV` alone should not be enough for sequentially consistent atomic store (see, e.g., [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html), or [Herb Sutter's lecture around 0:35:00](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2)). Therefore, I would expect `XCHG` or `MFENCE` for `#pragma omp atomic write seq_cst`.

Comment: However, assuming that the data is correctly aligned, mov *is* sufficient for the simple atomic (without seq_cst), since in X86 tearing cannot occur. (All of the bytes making up the value are written atomically by mov). Without the seq_cst the atomic construct does not also imply an OpenMP "flush".

Comment: @Jim Cownie: Are your sure about flush? From OpenMP Spec. 4.0: _A flush region **with a list** is implied at the following locations: At entry to and exit from the atomic operation performed in a **non-sequentially consistent atomic region**, where the list contains only the storage location designated as x according to the description of the syntax of the atomic construct in Section 2.12.6 on page 127._ And: _A flush region **without a list** is implied at the following locations: ... At entry to and exit from the atomic operation performed in a **sequentially consistent atomic region**._

Comment: @Daniel: See the 4.5 spec, which says: "Any atomic construct with a seq_cst clause forces the atomically performed operation to 17 include an implicit flush operation without a list." Since it calls out that case, I assume that that also implies that a construct without a seq_cst does not imply a flush. It also explicitly (though in non-normative text) says that "a non-sequentially consistent atomic construct has the same semantics as a memory_order_relaxed atomic operation in C++11/C11". (And, the text you quote only requires flushing the variable in question anyway, which a simple mov does.)

Comment: @Jim Cownie: The text I quoted is in 4.5 spec. as well, thus even non SC atomics imply flush, though flush with a list. And you are right that `mov` provides this. For SC atomics, I would expect additional fence to prevent reordering at CPU level, but it's not put in the program by g++ in my case. That is what I wodner about; does sequential consistency mean something different for OpenMP and C++11 memory models?

Comment: @Daniel. I think we're in violent agreement. The non-SC read/write operations don't need any memory fences on X86. The SC ones do. (And we were being confused by a gcc bug :-( ).

Comment: @Jim I think so as well :). Thanks for help